# Parsing data to page in Sail js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, sails.js

today i'm using sail js framework.
I got little bit confuse how to parse my data to my page.

```
getAddress(
  function (err, res){
    address = res;
    return address;
})
```

and will show in here:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">Public Address:</div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="address"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

how can i parse from my js file to my index page?

when i console log the address it show, but how can i put it into my p.address?
[image: browser-view]

Answer (score 0):

By using locals: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals

You would pass the data as an object as the second parameter when calling `res.view`

Then you may include it in the compiled HTML by referencing them using the view engine

```
<p class="address"><%= ip %></p>
```

An example:

```
res.view('someView', {
    address: somevar
});
```

Comment: so, for example you create variable in new js file.
let say:
var number = 1
then u return number

how can i parse number to my view page?
getAddress is just example, i'm not gonna show my ip-address.
ty

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined
that's what i've got

Comment: so this var is not come from database, the simple question that i wanna ask is, how can i throw data address from js file ( in js file i create var address = 'melbourne') and show it in my view.ejs. how to show address data in view.js. ohh this is very complicated for me, im sory im very noob

Comment: Within the route controller, you have req (request) and res (response), you call it from there. SailsJS doc covers most of these